drf_spectacular not picking up complex objects
I'm running Django with drf_spectacular
I have a serializer that looks something like this (greatly simplified)
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
     parameters = Parameters(many=True, default=[])



class Parameters(BaseSerializer):
    param_name = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
    param_count = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

The drf_spectacular annotations are
@extend_schema(
    request=None,
    responses={
        200: MySerializer,
        400: ErrorResponseSerializer,
        500: ErrorResponseSerializer
    },
    description="Load all data"
)

The swagger that is being generated for the parameters field is
  "parameters": [],

How can I get it to generate the contents of the list with a sample parameter object.  Why isn't drf_spectacular picking it up from the serializers?
For example, I would expect something like this
   "parameters": [
       {
         "string",
         "int"
        }
    ]

